# roc_auc_score mismatch between y_test and y_score

Tags: python, keras, auc

I'm trying to calculate the following:

```
auc = roc_auc_score(gt, pr, multi_class="ovr")
```

where `gt` is a list sized **3470208** containing values between 0 and 41 (all int) and `pr` is a list sized **3470208** (same size) of lists that each is sized 42 with probabilities in each location that sum up to 1.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of classes in y_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score'
```

So I am kind of lost as the number of classes in `y_true (gt)` is 42 because I have a list of integers from 0 to 41.

and since `pr` is a list of lists of size 42 then I think it should work.

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that **all** integers between 0 and 41 (inclusive) exist in gt.

A simple example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

# results in error:
gt1 = np.array([0,1,3])
pr1 = np.array(
    [[0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1], 
     [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2], 
     [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3]]
)
#roc_auc_score(gt1, pr1, multi_class='ovr')


# does not result in error:
gt2 = np.array([0,2,1,3])
pr2 = np.array(
    [[0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1], 
     [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2], 
     [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3],
     [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2]] 
)
#roc_auc_score(gt2, pr2, multi_class='ovr')
```

Because integer/label 2 is non-existent in gt1 it throws an error. In other words, *the number of classes in gt1* (3) is *not equal to the number of columns in pr1* (4).

Comment: And what should you do if one training label is not present in the test set?

Comment: Good question. I'm not really sure what approach is best here. Hopefully someone else can come with a good suggestion. :) 
I'm thinking, as that label can't be evaluated (roc_auc_score is undefined for that label), it could just be discarded? I.e., one could remove that column in y_pred ("pr"). Notice, if a column is removed after predictions have been generated, the remaining probabilities won't add up to 1, so rescaling would be needed.

Answer (score 4):

The **roc_auc_score** method has a **labels** parameter that can be used to specify missing labels.

Unfortunately, this only works with the multi_class="ovo" mode, and not the "ovr" mode.

```
# without labels
gt1 = np.array([0,1,3])
pr1 = np.array(
    [[0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1], 
     [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2], 
     [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3]]
)
roc_auc_score(gt1, pr1, multi_class='ovo')
> ValueError: Number of classes in y_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score'

# with labels and multi-class="ovo":
gt1 = np.array([0,1,3])
pr1 = np.array(
    [[0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1], 
     [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2], 
     [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3]]
)
roc_auc_score(gt1, pr1, multi_class='ovo', labels=[0, 1, 2, 3])
> 0.5

# with labels and multi-class="ovr":
gt1 = np.array([0,1,3])
pr1 = np.array(
    [[0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1], 
     [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2], 
     [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3]]
)
roc_auc_score(gt1, pr1, multi_class='ovr', labels=[0, 1, 2, 3])
> ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.
```

In this case, there is only one class present in **y_true** because the **roc_auc_score** function iterates over each class (identified as class A) and compares them with the other classes (identified as class B). For class 2, the y_true array is equal to [B, B, B] so there is only one class and the ROC AUC score cannot be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is always a good idea to make sure all test labels exist in the training set and vice versa. If you have labels that has single example it will be impossible to make test sets and training sets in that manner.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).